# Add ID to GeoJSON using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file in the following format:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "entities",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Layer": "111",
                "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline",
                "EntityHandle": "1E632"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -5.916278267253799,
                        54.60546220880693,
                        -5.5
                    ], etc
```

I want to add an ID to each feature, e.g. `1, 2, 3, etc`

I've tried the following code, which isn't throwing any errors but also isn't adding the ID

```
#create empty file to be writen to
file = open("new_file.geojson", "w")
count = 0

#read original file
with open('original_file.geojson', 'r')as myfile:
    for line in myfile:

       #lines that don't need to be edited with an 'id'
       if not line.startswith('{ "type": '):
            file.write(line)
       else:
            #lines that need to be edited
            count = count +1
            idNr = str(count)
            file.write(line[0:20] + '"id":'+ '"'+ idNr + '",' +line[21:])

file.close()
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You open the file with mode `r` so it won't write.

Comment: @BrainFl It still doesn't make a difference with the ```r``` removed. I'm still not getting an ID added to each feature :(

Comment: It's still kinda confusing about what you want to do. can you add more detail (like what to do with the JSON)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dicts keys in this way:

```
dict_element['key1']['key2']
```

But how there is some lists inside the dicts, you can access then with the lists index, do this in the right order untill 'features' level:

```
new_dict = dict_element['<key1>'][<index>]['features']
```

How the IDs are in the list level, you can just do a for loop in the right level and insert it in the index [0]:

```
i = 0
for i in range(len(new_dict)):

    new_dict[i].insert(0,i+1)
```